# Sharedpreference is given null pointer exception when activity kill or distroy in running app

Tags: android

```
  public class SharedPreferencesMain implements Constants
    {

        private static SharedPreferencesMain sharedPrefs;
        private static SharedPreferences sharedPrefrences;
        private SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
        private Context  context;

        private SharedPreferencesMain()
        {

        }

        public static SharedPreferencesMain getInstance(Context context)
        {
            if (sharedPrefs == null)
            {
                sharedPrefs = new SharedPreferencesMain(context);
                sharedPrefrences = context.getSharedPreferences(Preferences.REFFERAL_PREFERECNE, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            }

            return sharedPrefs;
        }

        // *************EMAIL ID**********************
        public void setEmailId(String setEmailId)
        {
            editor = sharedPrefrences.edit();
            editor.putString(Preferences.EMAILID, setEmailId);
            editor.commit();
        }

        public String getEmailId()
        {
            String emailId;
            emailId = sharedPrefrences.getString(Preferences.EMAILID, "");
            return emailId;
        }
    }
```

When any activity destroyed , stopped or killed in running app and recieve any  push notification then `sharedpreference` gives `null pointer exception.`

Answer (score 0):

You can change your class definition as below -

```
public class SharedPreferencesMain {

private static SharedPreferences sharedPrefrences;
private SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
private Context context;

private SharedPreferencesMain(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    sharedPrefrences = context.getSharedPreferences(Preferences.REFFERAL_PREFERECNE, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    editor = sharedPrefrences.edit();
}

// *************EMAIL ID**********************
public void setEmailId(String setEmailId) {
    editor.putString(Preferences.EMAILID, setEmailId);
    editor.commit();
}

public String getEmailId() {
    String emailId;
    emailId = sharedPrefrences.getString(Preferences.EMAILID, "");
    return emailId;
}
}
```

Now you can access it as below -

```
SharedPreferencesMain obj = new SharedPreferencesMain(MainActivity.this);
```

To set Email -

```
obj.setEmailId("sample@sample.com");
```

To get Email -

```
obj.getEmailId();
```

Answer (score 0):

> When any activity destroyed , stopped or killed in running app and
>   recieve any push notification then sharedpreference gives null pointer
>   exception.

that is most probably because you might be providing the context of Activity or classname.this from your activity to initialize sharedpreferences, so soon as activity is kicked out of memory stack objects related to it are deleted too so you get a null pointer exception. if you want sharedPreferences to be available in your whole app you need to provide Application Context.

@kevz
i think you forgot to pass context object in constructor.